# How to create EncryptColumn by Fluent Api on EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

There is a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn) that allows us to annotate a class with an EncryptColumn, in order to have a way of encrypting values on the SQL.

That approach demands an Attribute in the POCO Class, is there an alternative using the Fluent API of EF and configuring a certain Column as EncryptColumn?

Comment: just need that a certain field (secret key) to be encrypted when stored on the database.

Comment: Read the source of that package and you'll see how they are doing it. (https://github.com/emrekizildas/EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn/blob/main/EntityFramework.Core.EncryptDBColumn/Extension/ModelBuilderExtension.cs#L30)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use some 3rd party libraries for this one.

Examples

1. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn
2. https://github.com/Eastrall/EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption

Thanks,
Erandika

Comment: That was what I had on the post, but they use Attribute annotation on the classes, is there an alternative to use fluent API instead of attribute annotation?